# Отобразить WLAN-статус через python

Tags: python, winapi

Как отобразить статус сети - виртуальной точки доступа, запущенной через SoftAP, (запущена ли, вывести имя сети) которая в WinAPI вроде значится как *WlanHostedNetworkQueryStatus*.
Смотрел PyWin32, но не нашел подобных методов.

Comment: ну если нету, то юзайте GetProcAddress

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться модулем [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html).
Правда я не знаю как в ctypes обращаться к последнему полю структуры [WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_STATUS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/dd439510(v=vs.85).aspx).

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from ctypes import wintypes
import ctypes

WlanApi = ctypes.windll.wlanapi

hClientHandle = wintypes.HANDLE()
phClientHandle = ctypes.pointer(hClientHandle)
dwNegotiatedVersion = wintypes.DWORD()
pdwNegotiatedVersion = ctypes.pointer(dwNegotiatedVersion)
dwClientVersion = wintypes.DWORD()
dwClientVersion.value = 2L # WinVista, 7

rc = WlanApi.WlanOpenHandle(dwClientVersion, None, pdwNegotiatedVersion, phClientHandle)

if rc == 0:
    class WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_STATUS(ctypes.Structure):
        _fields_ = [("HostedNetworkState", ctypes.c_int),
                    ("IPDeviceID", wintypes.BYTE * 16),
                    ("wlanHostedNetworkBSSID", wintypes.BYTE * 6),
                    ("dot11PhyType", ctypes.c_int),
                    ("ulChannelFrequency", wintypes.ULONG),
                    ("dwNumberOfPeers", wintypes.DWORD),
                     # Последнее поле - массив неопределенного размера.
                     # В C++ для доступа к такому массиву используется прямой доступ к памяти (адресная арифметика)
                     # WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_PEER_STATE PeerList[1];
                    ]
    phNetworkStatus_t = ctypes.POINTER(WLAN_HOSTED_NETWORK_STATUS) # тип указателя на структуру
    phNetworkStatus = phNetworkStatus_t() #нулевой указатель
    # эта функция принимает указатель на указатель
    code = WlanApi.WlanHostedNetworkQueryStatus(hClientHandle, ctypes.byref(phNetworkStatus), 0)
    if code == 0:
        print "dwNumberOfPeers:", phNetworkStatus.contents.dwNumberOfPeers
```